# Is using RemoveIF() against SharePoint list consider a delegable operation or not

Tags: sharepoint-online, powerapp, powerapps-forms, powerapps-canvas, power-platform

I did not enable this experimental feature:

[image: johnjohnPter_0-1706715418776.png]

and at the same time I am using `RemoveIf()` on many scenarios such as:

[image: johnjohnPter_1-1706715497502.png]

and none of the `RemoveIf()` is raising delegation warning? so will the `RemoveIf()` in my case be delegable or not delegable?

Thanks.

Baseline, I am moving to production soon, so I do not want to enable any experimental features.

Comment: Are you trying to remove only single item at a time?

Comment: @Ganesh Sanap - MVP no multiple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, `RemoveIf()` function is not delegable with the SharePoint data source. Delegation support is in experimental phase currently.

Here is some information from the documentation:

[image]

But, if you are trying to delete only one item at a time (or less number of items than the "Data row limit" set in your app) using `RemoveIf()` function, it should work for you (without enabling experimental feature).

---

I did test from my end in Power Apps - here is the information and results:

**SharePoint List**:

- List name: ViewThreshold
- No. of items: 102524 (ID = 1 to ID = 102524)

**Canvas App**:

- Data row limit: 500
- Experimental feature for `RemoveIf()` - **Off**

Tried below formulas in application:

| Formula | Result |
| --- | --- |
| RemoveIf(ViewThreshold, ID=5); | Item deleted |
| RemoveIf(ViewThreshold, ID=102524); | Item deleted |
| RemoveIf(ViewThreshold, ID>102515); | Multiple items deleted |
| RemoveIf(ViewThreshold, Title="Item 102523"); | Item deleted |
| RemoveIf(SortByColumns(ViewThreshold,"ID",SortOrder.Descending), ID=102522); | Error - The specified data source cannot be used with this function. |
| Remove(ViewThreshold,LookUp(ViewThreshold,ID=102522)); | Item deleted using `Remove()` function |

Comment: so this mean as long as the number of items we want to delete are less than the Date row Limit, the RemoveIF will work fine, without enabling the experimental feature?

Comment: Yes, correct. No of items with the `RemoveIf()` function condition should be less than the data row limit so that all the expected items will be deleted.